# Runtime error when initializing multiple pointers

Tags: c++

This is probably just something I don't understand about c++, but why does this code give me a runtime error? If I don't initialize someInt2 or I don't specify that aClass has an int member, I don't get the error.

```
using namespace std;

class aClass
{
  int someint;
  public:
  aClass()
  {
    someint=4;
  }
};

int bFunc()
{
  return 4;
}


aClass aFunc()
{
  aClass class1=aClass();
  return class1;
}

int main()
{
  int * someInt2;
  *someInt2=bFunc();
  aClass * thisClass;
  cout << "Got here" << endl;
  *thisClass=aFunc();
  cout << "Not here" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int * someInt2;
*someInt2=bFunc();
```

Undefined behaviour. You didn't make `someInt2` point anywhere meaningful.

Edit: "Appearing to function correctly" is one of the possible things that "undefined behaviour" can be.

Comment: May I then ask why the function will run smoothly if I define aClass simply as class aClass{}; ?

Comment: Because apearing to run smoothly is one of the possible outcomes of running a program that contains undefined behaviour. Your program is ill-formed and the compiler isn't required to emit sensible code.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int * someInt2;
```

is an uninitialised pointer, and yet you are trying to assign a value to what it points to. You need to allocate some memory or simply use a `int` variable to store the return value of the function.